# How to retrieve all the vertices using its property value in JanusGraph?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I'm new to the **JanusGraph Database**. I have a requirement where I need to retrieve the vertices based on property values passed by user. Basically we are trying to search and get vertices by passing property values as comma separated strings.

Assume, one vertex contains a property called `name` and its value is `Janus`, and another vertex contains same property `name` and its value is `Graph`.

I could only be able to retrieve vertex based on single value like below,

`g.V().has("name", "Janus").valueMap()`

But what I would like to do is, I would like to pass values like

`Janus, Graph, ...`

and I'd like to get all the vertices which has these values for the property key `name`.

User can pass any number of *comma separated string values* but ultimately all the vertices which contains passed values has to be retrieved.

I'm in need of help.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `within`:

```
g.V().has("name", within("Janus", "Graph")).valueMap()
```

Comment: Hi @noam621, I have one more doubt, can we provide regular expression in the "within" method? Instead of placing full text? I have tried using "textRegex" and "textContainsRegex" methods but it's not working.

Comment: I actually don't have a lot of experience working with Janus, so I can't tell you how to combine the gremlin with their custom steps. maybe you should open a new question @Shr4N